# bigquery backend error - no more details available

Tags: google-bigquery

Job No: swift-sphinx-624:job_Ja1iYkl8OdF83J9xU5CIQJFlomM

Is failing, tried making the dataset public to no avail.  Any info more descriptive than 'backend error' would be greatly appreciated.

Really sorry but I just dont have anything more to give, error message is so undescriptive.

Comment: Please tell us what you tried.

Comment: Uploaded a large file (~2GB which is about 20GB uncompressed).  Initially took about 7 hours and then failed without any description above and beyond the 'backend error'.  The file and compression should be fine as I have other files that worked which were smaller (< 1gb compressed).  I'm just trialing big query so I'm using the web console so I don't have any exception or anything like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not upload a file that big to BigQuery. The proper way is to upload that file to google storage and then import from there. This process is much more reliable.

google's services fail. we have to account for that.

Load from Cloud Storage
https://developers.google.com/bigquery/loading-data-into-bigquery#loaddatagcs

Resumable uploads to Cloud Storage
https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp#resumable-transfers

I hope this helps!

Comment: This wasnt really the answer,  I had tried cloud storage.  I worked around the issue by splitting my file into 4 files.  Uploading them all to cloud storage and then appending them all to the same table.  I think it was just a size limitation thing.  Error message however is terrible